# SonarQube - Rule based on defined regular expression.

Tags: sonarqube

Does SonarQube have a rule which will scan a files content for a reqular expression and if found during a scan will mark as an issue?

Example:
I want a rule which that will scan each file for the word "AcmeProducts" and mark it as "Critical" if found.

Thanks
Jason

Comment: You could write your own coding rule. See [here](https://docs.sonarqube.org/display/DEV/Adding+Coding+Rules+using+Java)

Answer (score 1):

I was able to accomplish this by creating a custom rule based on the Comment pattern matcher rule in sonarqube.

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to come back and answer your own question :) But can you please share how you were able to extract the default rule? I cant figure it out.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if such rule exists.
You could implement a custom plugin to provide such rule.

Something that's very close to what you need is the [`HasTagSensor`](https://github.com/SonarSource/sonarqube/blob/master/plugins/sonar-xoo-plugin/src/main/java/org/sonar/xoo/rule/HasTagSensor.java) of the Xoo Plugin, which is not a real plugin, but a sample to demonstrate and test features of the plugin API.
The `HasTag` rule implementation that I linked raises an issue for each occurrence of some configured string (not a regex).
Based on this, you could implement a rule that uses a regex parameter instead of a string.

Answer (score 0):

I think that what you are looking for is implemented in the sonar checkstyle plugin.

To configure such a rule :

1. Install the sonar checkstyle plugin. The instructions to follow is
   given here, on the sonar checkstyle plugin GitHub page :
   https://github.com/checkstyle/sonar-checkstyle.
2. Reboot your sonar instance to make the new plugin available
3. Configure a new rule, using the following menu sequence :

   - "Quality profile"
   - select the quality profile to modify
   - in the rule list, select "Activate more"
   - in the "repository" section, select "checkstyle" to filter checkstyle's plugin rules
   - select the rule template "Regexp Singleline" and create a new rule base on a regex detecting your prohibited key word.